# How to remove current date highlight and restrict future and current date from selecting?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to remove current date highlight and restrict future and current date from selecting, I tried this below code

```
$(".datepick").datepicker("destroy");
$(".datepick").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    maxDate: 0,
});
```

This above one is restricting future dates but not current date.

```
$(".ui-datepicker-today a").removeClass("ui-state-default ui-state-highlight ui-state-active");
```

tried this too to remove the current date highlight but it is not removing.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77569558/edit) your question to include your attempts and clarify specifics. The current form is broad and lacks code, risking closure. Refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [Homework Guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#10812) for better structuring. Improved questions have a higher chance of staying open and receiving answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 $(".datepick").datepicker("destroy");
                $(".datepick").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                    selectOtherMonths: true,
                    //minDate: new Date(),
                    maxDate: 0,
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                       
                        var currentDate = new Date();

                       
                        if (date.getFullYear() === currentDate.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() === currentDate.getMonth() && date.getDate() === currentDate.getDate())
                        {
                          return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    
                    }
                    
                });
```

Comment: Could you explain why this answers your question? Because only code doesn't explain very much

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. According to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) a value of `-1` will set the maximum date to yesterday:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    maxDate: -1
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```